# URL of image from Image Library

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

**How to take `URL` (which SharePoint Column) of an image from the Image library(Angular)?**

I have tried this

```
<div id="firstdiv" style="border:solid #9C1327;padding:5px 5px 20px 5px;">{{contents[0].Name}}</div></div>
```

Comment: Have no idea what you are asking or what the code shown has to do with an image or a url.

Comment: sorry i pasted wrong code right code is below                                     <div class="tabImages">
   <img ng-src={{contents[0].Image.Url}} width="48" height="48"/>
   
  </div>

Comment: i found the answer it is {{contents[0].EncodedAbsUrl}}